# Requesting JSON input from Postman to run API

Tags: python, api, flask, postman

I am new to Postman.I have build Machine learning model and trying to predict the new data using api.I am using below code :

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/model_prediction', methods = ['POST'])
def model_prediction():
    
    dic_data = request.form 
    file_path= dic_data["file_path"]
    print(file_path)
    input_data = request.json
    print(input_data)
    prediction_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
    prediction_data =prediction_data.T
    print(prediction_data)
    
    with open(file_path+'/decisiontree.pkl','rb') as f:
            model = pickle.load(f)
        
    prediction = model.predict(prediction_data)
    
    return jsonify('preidiction is :',prediction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

While running this API on Postman, I want to get two input. One is `file_path` and another data in json format.Below is screenshot of how I am passing the values :

[image: img-1]

[image: img-2]

with the above process I am getting the below error as :

[image: img-3]

I am not able to identify the error here and got stuck.Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You cannot use two different formats for the same request. You can only select one of the radio buttons, either "form" or "raw", but you cannot mix and match them

Comment: Also, what are the numbers you currently have in the "raw" body? And what do you expect the file at `file_path` to contain?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix-and-match `request.form` and `request.json`. You can use one or the other, but not both at the same time. For a REST API, you should only use `request.json`. You can easily do this by accepting two keys: `file_path` and `data`. So you can do something like this in Postman using a "raw" body format:

```
{
    "file_path": "/path/to/the/file",
    "data": [ ...all the numbers here ... ]
}
```

Now in your code, you can access `request.json['file_path']` and `request.json['data']` to get each of these.

Although, I highly recommend against allowing the user to specify the `file_path` in the JSON. How are they supposed to know the path of a file on the server? And if they do, this opens a security risk because they can try to read a file anywhere in the system.

Comment: Thank You for your response. This is just for testing purpose.